# Idea on expansion and collaboration of the Drupal community

Tags: discussion

Would it be possible to speak with the moderators of drupal.org into merging their Q&A + Forum with stackexchange's system? Combining the user base of drupal.org with the usability of the stackexchange system would benefit the Drupal community 10 fold. It's a win-win situation.

What do you think are the pros and cons of this idea? Is this even feasible?

Comment: Drupal.org doesn't have any Q&A, so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open issue in the Drupal.org webmasters queue: http://drupal.org/node/1236290